# Elasticsearch in Go, Err: "the client noticed that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not support this unknown product"

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm working on using Elasticsearch in Go, I followed this guide: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/04/23/elasticsearch-go-developers-guide

I set up Elastic with docker.
Verify that Elasticsearch is running:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "0e9e2916eca5",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "jh8PVKNASpO3uK87Jzoq6Q",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "8bec50e1e0ad29dad5653712cf3bb580cd1afcdf",
    "build_date" : "2020-01-15T12:11:52.313576Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Also from the browser seems fine.

Next I set up a sample Go program just to test it out:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v8"
)

func Test_elastic(t *testing.T) {

    es, err := elasticsearch.NewDefaultClient()
    if err != nil {
     panic(err)
    }

    res, err := es.Info()
    if err != nil {
     panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
}
```

but res returns with err:

> "the client noticed that the server is not Elasticsearch and we do not
> support this unknown product"

Digging in the code I see it verifies the response by looking for `header.Get("X-Elastic-Product") == "Elasticsearch"`.

I have no idea why it's not working and I couldn't find any reference for this error online... would appreciate any input on this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the header. Adding the header helped me with my mock test.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are using v8 of the elasticsearch client, but v7.5.2 of elasticsearch itself. You need to use the library version corresponding to the elasticsearch version, like `github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7`. It seems that the check for the header was only added [recently](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/pull/324/files) in order to not make the library work with any forks.

Comment: with python client got the same error with minors. had 7.10 installed (opensearch, actually), and with 7.15 client was getting this error. downgrading to 7.10 works!

Comment: @suren in Python you can do this to bypass the check: `client = Elasticsearch(...) client._verified_elasticsearch = True`

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @izolight's answer, You can use any old version that works for you and where the validation is not added. The go-elasticsearch `v7.13.1` and `v6.8.10` are the latest versions without the product check.

**go.mod:**

```
    github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7 v7.13.1
    github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v6 v6.8.10
```

**sample.go:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/v7"
)

func Test_elastic(t *testing.T) {

    es, err := elasticsearch.NewDefaultClient()
    if err != nil {
     panic(err)
    }

    res, err := es.Info()
    if err != nil {
     panic(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
}
```

**Off-Topic:**

By doing this, the Elasticsearch forks like OpenSearch won't be able to use `go-elasticsearch` client. Same product checks are added to other client libraries, say [elastic/elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/pull/1623).

In response, Amazon has planned to fork the Client libraries too and maintain them as like OpenSearch.

- [Keeping clients of OpenSearch and Elasticsearch compatible with open source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/keeping-clients-of-opensearch-and-elasticsearch-compatible-with-open-source/)

Answer (score 3):

Just a side note that if you are writing tests against ES and running into this issue when following the recommendation to use a mock for a custom http.Transport, make sure your mock response includes the headers, as seen at https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/elasticsearch_internal_test.go#L53